# Declaring a function in a parameter list in python

Tags: python

I'm looking to build a generic object for curve fitting, where I define parameter names, values and bounds. Sometimes, I want to use the incoming data to help define the bounds using a function (min, max, etc.).

Here is the object:

```
class CurveFitObject(object):
    def __init__(self,paramList,growthEquation):
        self.paramList = paramList
        self.gmod = Model(growthEquation)

    def calcCurveFit(data):
     for param in self.paramList:
            self.gmod.set_param_hint(self.paramList['name'],
                                     value=self.paramList['value'](data),
                                     min=self.paramList['min'](data),
                                     max=self.paramList['max'](data))
```

Here I am trying to use np.min(data) as my guess, 0.975 * np.min(data) as my lower bound, and 1.025 * np.min(data) as my upper bound.

```
def growthEquation(self, t, A): return A
keys = ['name','guess','min','max','vary']
logisticGrowth = CurveFitObject(
                                [dict(zip(keys,['A',np.min,0.975*np.min,1.025*np.min,True])),
                                growthEquation
                                )
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'`
which makes sense since it's trying to do math on the function `0.975*np.min` rather than `0.975*np.min(data)`.

What is the best way to implement this behavior? If any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a wrapper for an existing function.  For example, you have:

```
0.975*np.min
```

But this doesn't work, since it's trying to multiply a `float` times a function.  You can create a new function inline by using:

```
lambda data: 0.957*np.min(data)
```

This is probably what you're looking for.  It's equivalent to defining a named function:

```
def myfunc(data):
    return 0.957*np.min(data)
```

and then using `myfunc`.  The difference is that the `lambda` syntax creates an anonymous function that can be defined inline.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.